# how do i send different email notifications for different ways a form was edited in php?

Tags: php, forms, email

form has different inputs/fields.  i want to notify someone with an email when different things happen.  for example i want to email a person when record is approved, which works with the below code, but then if the form is edited and submitted again for a different reason, meaning changing other fields but leaving the approved field as approved, the email notification gets sent out again telling about approval, when that's not what was edited.

so how can i change this to only email once when just approval field is changed from no to yes, and editing the form again and keeping approved status to yes does not send email notification again?

also i want to send another email if other fields are changed, but those other fields are not zeros and ones, they are random text.

so basically i want to send specific emails for specific things that were edited in form.

if approved status was changed, send email about approval only.  if prices were changed, send email about price change only.  if approval and prices were changed, send email that approval status and prices were changed.

know what i mean?

```
if ($approved == 1) {
  $to = $email;
  $subject = 'Job# '.$id.' has been approved by an Admin';
  $message = "You can now view job# ".$id."!\n\n.";
  $headers = "From: info@domain.com\r\nReply-To: info@domain.com";
  $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

UPDATE:

never got this to work with any of the tips, tricks, help, suggestions, etc.

i ended up just creating a separate checkbox that an admin needs to check to email the owner of job when different things are edited.  one checkbox for approval emailing and another for everything else.  the everything else can be for unapproving, for changing prices, for changing anything in the job form.  also added a textarea box for admin to write whatever he/she wants to clarify things when job owner receives his/her email notification.

Comment: so.. write a bunch of conditional code `if ($condition_set_1_is_met) { send email type #1 } else if ($condition_set_2_is_met) { send email type #2 } etc...`.

Comment: alternatively, you can use switch() function to render different `$message` and `$subject` value and run the email sending code once, instead of repetitive code - http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: Is this data being stored in a database? If so when the submit is triggered check to see what has changed in the database using and the post values if they are different do a case statement based on that

Comment: yes the info is in database.  also, how does 2nd rule or case negate 1st rule, meaning if 2nd thing is true the first one might be true too, but don't do 1st if you're doing 2nd?

Comment: not sure i said that right.  here is another way to say it.  when form is changed and approval is changed to yes, it's true on first edit and it's true for every other edit because approval will always be 1.

Comment: Yes, so what you would do would be grab that row in the database and write an if statement

`if($row['approved'] == 1)
{

      //Do different email
}

else
{

//If not previously approved

if($_POST['approved'] == 1
{

//Send approval email

}

//Else nothing will happen

}`

Answer (score 0):

Cross referencing data from the database to the posted data would allow you to only send emails once, for each thing you do.

For example;

```
// check the data has been posted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
    // do some checking of data here 
    // (array_key_exists/isset/ctype_digit/ctype_alnum or whatever)
    $id  = $_POST['id'];

    // Construct the query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '{$id}'";

    // You're possibly using mysqli_, but for arguments sake, I'll use mysql_
    $run = mysql_query($sql); 

    // Check there is a result
    if (mysql_num_rows($run) == 1)
    {

        // Give the query above a variable to call from
        $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($run);

        // Now that you are here and $item is set, you should check your data.

        // For example, if you have posted to approve the item, check that it's 
        // not been approved already
        if ($_POST['approved'] == 1 && $item['approved'] == 0)
        {
            // If you are here, you have opted to approve it, 
            // but it wasn't approve, so send email.

            // ADD FUNCTION FOR EMAIL HERE //
        }
        // Don't bother with an IF clause, since you don't need the code to do anything
    }
}
```

Note, where I have wrote "// ADD FUNCTION FOR EMAIL HERE //", a basic 2 parameter email could do. Something like;

```
function send_item_email($email, $flag)
{

}
```

Inside of that, you could use the flag to "switch" between options for the information posted.

```
function send_item_email($email, $flag)
{
    $subject = 'Generic Subject';
    switch ($flag) 
    {
        case "approved":
            "Your {{ITEM}} has been approved.";
        break;

        case "price":
            "The price of your {{ITEM}} has changed.";
        break;
    }
}
```

Using a function for the email (Like the swiftMailer wrapper) allows you to write minimal code in the updating part of the form, while allowing you to add flags to give set criteria in the email to send out.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: And given that you update the approved from 0 to 1, requiring $approval to be 1, would make it send out every time, whereas the first time you approve, it should fail since PHP would have pre-loaded the variable values to compare with, rendering $approved as 0.